# design issue related to strategy pattern

Tags: c#

I am trying to implement a kind of strategy pattern but not sure how to make the strategy interface as 
generic.

Please see my sample code below:

```
 public interface ISerializer
 {
    XDocument Serialize(PharmacyProductDto presetDataDto);
    XDocument Serialize(PatientDto presetDataDto);
    PrescriberDto Deserialize(PrescriberDto xDocument);
 }

  public class XmlSerializer : ISerializer
  {
    public XDocument Serialize(PharmacyProductDto presetDataDto)
    {
        return new XDocument();
    }

    public XDocument Serialize(PatientDto presetDataDto)
    {
        return new XDocument();
    }

    public PrescriberDto Deserialize(PrescriberDto xDocument)
    {
        return new PrescriberDto();
    }
  }

  public class PatientDto
  {
  }

public class PrescriberDto
{
}

public class PharmacyProductDto
{
}
```

Here you can see that ISerializer which basically serializes different DTOs. 
The XmlSerializer class becomes very clumsy as it serialize many types. Also, I will be adding some more types in future.

I thought of implementing a strategy pattern here. Something like this:

```
public interface ISerializerStrategy
    {
        XDocument Serialize(PatientDto presetDataDto);
        PatientDto Deserialize(XDocument xDocument);
    }

public class PatientDtoSerializerStrategy : ISerializerStrategy
{

}

public class PrescriberDtoSerializerStrategy : ISerializerStrategy
{

}
```

But you can see that `ISerializerStrategy` is very concrete to `PatientDto`. How can I make this interface abstract or generic which will also work for
`PrescriberDtoSerializerStrategy`?

Can someone suggest to me?

Comment: Will serialize always serialize to xml?

Comment: @Nkosi: Yes. I think michael's help is the one I am looking for. But since in my older implementation I use to inject the interface, but now with generic interface I am not sure how to use it

Answer (score 4):

Use a generic interface:

```
public interface ISerializerStrategy<T>
{
    XDocument Serialize(T presetDataDto);
    T Deserialize(XDocument xDocument);
}

public class PatientDtoSerializerStrategy : ISerializerStrategy<PatientDto>
{
    XDocument Serialize(PatientDto presetDataDto);
    PatientDto Deserialize(XDocument xDocument);
}

public class PrescriberDtoSerializerStrategy : ISerializerStrategy<PrescriberDto>
{
    XDocument Serialize(PrescriberDto presetDataDto);
    PrescriberDto Deserialize(XDocument xDocument);
}
```

**Usage**

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo(ISerializerStrategy<PrescriberDto> serializer)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

**Registration**

```
container.RegisterType<ISerializerStrategy<PrescriberDto>, PrescriberDtoSerializerStrategy>();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. But now I am stuck with another problem.
With the older implementation, I was injecting ISerializer via unity container to other classes to use it via.

But with your solution, now the interface is generic ISerializerStrategy<T>.

How can I inject it? or use it

Comment: In this scenario  you have to  be dependent on `ISerializerStrategy<PatientDto>`. The other approach is to make a more generic serializer. See this [fiddler](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0x4lax) example for inspiration.